# Is there a way to feed images of different classes, all in one directory, with their corresponding classes to in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to perform image classification on a mixed dataset of five classes. all images are in the same directory. I want to use the handy *image_dataset_from_directory* method of *keras.preprocessing*. But since the files are all in one directory it only detects one class for all of them. I also used *labels* parameter setting it to a list of length equal to the number of images I have containing the labels, but it only reads them in one class.

```
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    "trainset",
    labels = trainlabels,
    image_size=image_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
)



Found 4987 files belonging to 1 classes.
```

Comment: keras needs something to define which image belongs to which class. You need to provide that info. What keeps you from putting them into different folders?

Comment: I actually did provide this information using the *labels* parameter. But still no luck. I did also use *shutil* and *os* to put them in different directories, but it would be nice to know if there is a way around it.